# Array of structs each containing dynamic arrays

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, dynamic, struct

I'm somewhat well-versed with C and I thought I had pointers all figured out until I ran into this problem. I'm creating an array-implemented stack of structs. Easy enough, but I'm running into a problem when my struct contains a dynamically allocated array.

The struct is:

```
typedef struct state {
    int* S;
    double prob;
} state_t;
```

Now say I'd like to create an array of 10 of those structs, each with an integer array of say 5 integers. I can allocate that array as:

```
state_t *newContents;
newContents = (state_t *)malloc((sizeof(state_t) + 5 * sizeof(int)) * 10);
```

And I can create a struct to go in the first slot:

```
state_t *root = malloc(sizeof *root + 5 * sizeof(int));
root->prob = 1.0;
root->S[0] = 3;
root->S[1] = 5;
root->S[2] = 7;
root->S[3] = 2;
root->S[4] = 0;
newContents[0] = *root;
```

But when I attempt to add a second struct, Seg fault. It's because the way the array is indexing is by the size of the struct without the int array, meaning each entry is 16 bytes long - 8 for the double + 8 for the pointer. I want it to instead index by 28 - 8 for the double and 4*5 for the ints. Does anyone know a way to access elements of this array correctly?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you check the content of `root`s member after you assigend values to them? Especially check the value of `prob`!

Answer (score 4):

You're allocating your structs wrong. The struct itself is separate from its dynamically-allocated array and needs to be allocated separately:

```
// Allocate the structs.
state_t *newContents = malloc(10*sizeof(*newContents));

// Allocate the S array of the first struct.
newContents[0].S = malloc(5*sizeof(int));
newContents[0].S[0] = 3;
...
```

If you want a struct that actually *contains* an array of runtime-determined length, rather than pointing to one as your current struct does, you need a flexible array member:

```
struct state_t {
    double prob;
    int S[]; // No length specified!
};
```

Then you can `malloc(sizeof(state_t) + n*sizeof(int))` and actually get a contiguous block of memory where the struct and its array are together. However, you can't put make an array of `state_t`s properly if you do this, since the compiler would have no idea where one struct ends and another begins.

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
state_t *newContents;
newContents = malloc(sizeof(state_t)*10);

int i;
for (i=0;i<10;i++)
   (newContents+i)->S=malloc(5 * sizeof(int));
```

If you want `newContents` to be an array of structs of size 10, then it should allocate size equal to `sizeof(state_t)*10`. The `int *`s within each struct should be allocated explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Using

1. [Arrays of Length Zero](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html) and GCC extensions of it
2. proper type casting
3. proper pointer arithmetic

you could get what you want, more or less.

Here is my testing program (compiling with `gcc -std=c99`):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct state {
    double prob;
    int S[];
} state_t;

int main(void) {
    size_t stateSize;
    state_t *newContents;
    stateSize = sizeof(state_t) + 5*sizeof(int);
    newContents = malloc(stateSize * 10);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        state_t *state = (state_t *)((char *)newContents + i * stateSize);
        state->prob = i;
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            state->S[j] = i * j;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        state_t *state = (state_t *)((char *)newContents + i * stateSize);
        printf("[%d] prob: %f\n", i, state->prob);
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            printf("\tS[%d]: %d\n", j, state->S[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Run:

```
$ ./a.out 
[0] prob: 0.000000
    S[0]: 0
    S[1]: 0
    S[2]: 0
    S[3]: 0
    S[4]: 0
[1] prob: 1.000000
    S[0]: 0
    S[1]: 1
    S[2]: 2
    S[3]: 3
    S[4]: 4
[2] prob: 2.000000
    S[0]: 0
    S[1]: 2
    S[2]: 4
    S[3]: 6
    S[4]: 8
[3] prob: 3.000000
    S[0]: 0
    S[1]: 3
    S[2]: 6
    S[3]: 9
    S[4]: 12
[4] prob: 4.000000
    S[0]: 0
    S[1]: 4
    S[2]: 8
    S[3]: 12
    S[4]: 16
[5] prob: 5.000000
    S[0]: 0
    S[1]: 5
    S[2]: 10
    S[3]: 15
    S[4]: 20
[6] prob: 6.000000
    S[0]: 0
    S[1]: 6
    S[2]: 12
    S[3]: 18
    S[4]: 24
[7] prob: 7.000000
    S[0]: 0
    S[1]: 7
    S[2]: 14
    S[3]: 21
    S[4]: 28
[8] prob: 8.000000
    S[0]: 0
    S[1]: 8
    S[2]: 16
    S[3]: 24
    S[4]: 32
[9] prob: 9.000000
    S[0]: 0
    S[1]: 9
    S[2]: 18
    S[3]: 27
    S[4]: 36
```